# How to save an index in lambda, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm trying to do the following:

```
>>>func = lambda string,i=0: string[index]

>>> func('HEY')
H
>>> func('HEY')
E
>>> func('HEY')
Y
```

How can i save and increment index each time(without creating index as global)
thanks

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want an iterator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can create a generator function, like this

```
def get_next_char(actual_string):
    for char in actual_string:
        yield char
```

Then, you need to create a generator object, like this

```
next_char = get_next_char("HEY")
```

That's it. You can now get the next character with `next` function, like this

```
>>> next(next_char)
H
>>> next(next_char)
E
>>> next(next_char)
Y
```

**Solution 2**

You can simply use the String's iterator, like this

```
get_char = iter("HEY")
>>> next(get_char)
H
>>> next(get_char)
E
>>> next(get_char)
Y
```

Comment: Can you show me how to convert the 'get_next_char' function to lambda? if it's possible ?

Comment: @ArnoldOsipov lambda functions and normal functions, cannot retain states, unless they are bound to an object or global objects. So, it is not possible with them :(